# How to exclude media folder when deploying to railway

Tags: django, deployment, django-media, whitenoise, railway

I have a django app hosted in railway, when I push the changes to github railway overrides the media folder as well and I lose all my images, is there a way to exclude the media folder from changing? (I tried gitignore and it didn't work), I'm using whitenoise to handle media and gunicorn to deploy the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted their support and they said the storage for Railway is ephemeral and the data on disk is cleared on each deployment, so we have to host our files elsewhere (I will try AWS S3 Buckets and edit this answer later)